# Display Date in special format in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs, angular8

I am looking for a JavaScript ES7 Method, which will convert `new Date()` into the following format below. Is there an ES7 method which will do this, or else I can manually parse/find/replace myself.

```
2020-06-30 07.49.28
```

Date with hyphen,  time with period.

Currently using typescript in Angular 8, however JavaScript syntax will also work.

Also open to Angular Method, Moment, Lodash or other library method.

*If none available, will take simplest find/replace/regex method,

Comment: a variation on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: hi @BryanOfEarth saw that already, question does not fully account for time functions, kind of general

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If u want to display in html then use [datepipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

```
<h1>{{date |date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm ss'  }}</h1>
```

Typescript:

```
let newDateFormat = (new DatePipe('en-US').transform(new Date(), 'MM-dd-yyyy hh.mm.ss'));
```

if u want format date for other things like assigning to file Name, then use [ngx-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-moment)
and make ur life easy
u can format ur date like this

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH.mm.ss');
```

Comment: ok, I also need to store as Typescript variable, in console log, this will work also

Comment: its a bad idea to store date in variable as string. bcs when ever u have to use it in any computation u have to parse it to date.

its better to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-moment it better then native date.

Comment: yep, placed in your answer suggestion queue

Answer (score 0):

You mention [momentJS](https://momentjs.com/), that library makes formatting dates very straightforward with a [`.format()` method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

```js
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH.mm.ss');
```

Note: `new Date()` is implicit when you [invoke `moment()` without an argument](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code, i am sure you can improve it

```
var d = new Date("06/30/2020 07:49:28");
var date = [
  d.getFullYear(),
  ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
  ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2),
 
].join('-');
console.log("date: ",date);

var time=[
 ('0' + d.getHours()) .slice(-2),
  ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
    ('0' + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2),

].join('.');
console.log("time: ",time);
console.log("result: ",date+" "+time);
```